# Determine if glyph exists in a font on WinCE

Tags: c++, mfc, windows-ce

The generic Windows API provides the GetGlyphIndices() function which determines if a particular glyph in a given font is renderable.  However, this function is not available within the WinCE 6.0 API and I require something similar in order to properly display Unicode text in MFC-based controls on an embedded platform.

Is there a standard function that achieves this or is it necessary to examine the underlying rendering process to determine glyph validity?